# Double integral of $e^{2(x+y)}(1+e^y)$ on a set D

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have a set $=\{(x,y)\in R^2: e^y-2 \le x\le e^y,-y-1 \le x \le -y+1\}$ and I want calculate $\int_D e^{2(x+y)}(1+e^y) dx dy$.

Can I use a change of coordinates as $u=x-e^y,v=x+y$?

Answer (score 0):

The change of variable you suggest could definitely work, provided you're comfortable with using the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Solving for $x$ and $y$, you have
$$\begin{cases}x=u+W(e^{v-u})\\y=v-u-W(e^{v-u})\end{cases}$$
which changes your integral to
$$\iint_Ee^{2(x+y)}(1+e^y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-2}^0\frac{e^{2v}\left(1-e^{v-u-W(e^{v-u})}\right)}{|1+W(e^{v-u})|}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v$$
where the Jacobian for your change of variable is the absolute value expression in the denominator. (I take no credit for coming up with this form of the integral on my own; all courtesy of Mathematica)

This happens to have a nice closed form, but I'll avoid including it here for lack of being able to compute it myself.

Comment: i don't know the Lambert-W function.

Comment: is there another way to solve tis problem?

Comment: maybe I can do another change of coordinates?

Comment: @GiuliaB. It might be possible. I haven't made any other attempts just yet. This change of variables is simplest in that it yields the simplest region of integration (a rectangle).